# Unable to view images on server built with TypeORM

Tags: typescript, image, typeorm

I'm new to typeorm. Here is what I want to achieve

"I want to view the images in my assets folder on the browser"

I have google this but I can't solve the problem

With node.js the following code solves the problem.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('assets/'));
app.listen(8000, ()=> console.log('server is running'));
```

I could access the images in my assets folder from browser url
e.g http://localhost:8000/images/sliders/dataLab3.jpg

How do I achieve this with typeorm ?
Here is what I have tried with typeorm

```js
// WITH TYPEORM
import express, { Express, Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
const app: Express = express();
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';
createConnection();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static('assets/')); 
app.listen(9000, ()=> console.log(`Server is running`));
```

When I access http://localhost:9000/images/sliders/dataLab3.jpg I get the following error message "Cannot GET /images/sliders/dataLab3.jpg"

Here is my observation after running tsc -w

1. A "build" folder is generated containing the js version of type script
2. The assets (images) are not in the build folder

I'm using "typeorm": "0.2.38",

Here is the tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "es5",
            "es6",
            "esnext.asynciterable"
        ],
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "./build",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}
```

Can someone help me out please

Comment: ```createConnection(...)``` returns a [**Promise**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) so you must put it inside an ```async``` function.

Comment: The *Typescript* compiler transforms only *.ts* files. Other files (e.g images) are ignored. You must use a custom script or something else (e.g Bundlers) to copy non .ts files into the build *folder*. In one of my projects (see [here](https://github.com/carlocorradini/happypuppy-server)) there is a npm script called ```build``` that compiles the .ts files and after copies all the "non .ts files" into the build folder (calling another script).

Comment: Thanks @Carlo can you share with me a working example because after spending several hours yesterday I'm still unable to resolve this.

Comment: See [https://github.com/carlocorradini/happypuppy-server](https://github.com/carlocorradini/happypuppy-server). If you can, share your work :)

Comment: @Carlo Conrradini thanks thus far for your responses. I've created a small app for this purpose only here is the url https://github.com/timothyuijiatalor/testApi

Comment: See [this pull request](https://github.com/timothyuijiatalor/testApi/pull/1). Accept and merge. Follow the instructions in the README :)